# Still able to retrieve Stream from TCPClient after remote client has called Dispose()

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

I have a simple client / server project, both running on my local machine.

In my client project, I am able to run the following (simplified) test code:

```
using(var tcpClient = new System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient())
{
  tcpClient.ConnectAsync(host, port).Wait(Timespan.FromSeconds(3));
  using (NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream())
  {
    ns.Write("Hello World", 0, "Hello World".Length);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
  }
}
```

This should write "Hello World" to the stream, then dispose everything after ~100ms, therefore making it unreadable after this point.

The problem is, the `TcpListener` running in my server project, is able to do roughly the following:

```
TcpClient client = TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
Thread.Sleep(750);
var stream = client.GetStream();  //I am still able to read the contents of this - shouldnt it be closed?
```

Could this be a problem caused by running the client/server on the same machine? Or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the `Dispose()` calls made on the client.

Comment: `do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the Dispose() calls` - could be. You dispose your instance of `tcpClient`, not anything else. That does not revoke bytes that have been sent, nor does it deliver a *faster than light* message to the server to stop reading whatever it might be reading.

Comment: I believe your data has been actually already sent, so `GetStream` just creates stream over received data from the rx socket buffer.

Comment: @Gserg GetStream() is called after both the network stream and the client have been disposed in the client end?

Comment: You have disposed your side of the connection. You have not invalidated the contents of the network card buffer on the server.

Comment: where do you close the stream... Is your first method a representation of AcceptTcpClient?

Comment: @johnny5 the the second using statement will dispose of 'ns' after the thread.sleep returns

Comment: @maxp I get that but its unclear where you make a call to the code above.  Your second example makes a call to `AcceptTcpClient` is this what calls the first snippet of code?

Comment: @maxp from the looks of it, you have 2 applications 1 client, which sends a message and closes the stream, and one server which just reads the stream.    If they are two seperate applications the disposes are not connected because you've initialized a seperate TCPClient on the Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the `Dispose()` calls made on the client.

You certainly seem to.

[Disposing a `TcpClient()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs,e70aabe5304f5cb1) for which `GetStream()` has been called disposes that local `NetworkStream`. In turn, [disposing that stream](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/NetworkStream.cs,398ae016b31720b8) calls `Shutdown()` on the underlying socket, and then closes the socket, freeing the native handle for it. (The latter two actions are taken in `TcpClient`, if no stream has been created yet. I.e. they will always happen regardless.)

That's all. Nothing else.

If you have sent data on the socket (and you have), and then waited long enough for that data to be transmitted (and you have), then the data is no longer in your control. And in fact, conceptually it's no longer under your control the moment you hand it to the socket. Even if in some cases you're able to get rid of the socket fast enough to prevent data from being sent, you shouldn't count on this. And in practice, the network drivers generally work very hard to transmit any data they've been given, no matter what happens on the local socket side.

So, yes. If you expect that closing the local socket after you've already sent data is somehow going to affect whether the remote endpoint is able to receive the data that you've already sent, you do in fact have a fundamental misunderstanding of the `Dispose()` calls made on the client (the local socket).

Comment: Thanks for the super answer. Is it then possible to check the state of the calling TCPClient from the server after the stream has been read? (To determine if it still exists)

Comment: As a general rule, no. The local endpoint has very little information about the state of the remote endpoint. If the remote endpoint has shutdown and/or closed the socket, the local endpoint can find that out, i.e. attempts to send data will fail with an exception, and a read operation will either complete with a 0-byte length or fail with an exception. But once those events occur, that's the end of any knowledge on the local endpoint's part regarding the state of the remote endpoint.